# How can I demonstrate that my data is sampled from a Gaussian process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

I have an experiment that, I believe, produces data with Gaussian noise. That is, any subset of my data points have a joint multivariate normal distribution with covariance K (i.e., they are sampled from a function with a Gaussian Process prior). To simplify, suppose the mean function is zero, so the statistical model is:

$$
\mathbf{D} \sim N(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{K})
$$
Where the covariance has a stationary kernel plus independent noise:
$$
K_{ij} = k(|\mathbf{d}_i-\mathbf{d}_j|) + \sigma_n^2\delta_{ij}
$$

For example, $k$ may be a square-exponential kernel. I would like to compute a metric from my real data that indicates $k$ indeed has the correct functional form (including, that it's not just zero everywhere!).

Just to emphasize: this is a very high dimensional problem because the size of **D** is huge.

Comment: The word "noise" suggests that your experimental data contains "measurement errors" that are normally distributed but with some kind of multivariate correlation.  I'd guess it is important to model the measurement errors separately from the underlying values-to-be-measured.  But your Question doesn't set up a framework in which we can discuss statistical tests that could (for example) discriminate between correlated and uncorrelated "noise".

Comment: @hardmath Thanks, and yes, I see what you mean. I will try to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

A visual way to see it is to do a qq-plot. Take a bunch of $N(0,K)$ random variables (like via MATLAB's randn) and plot the quantiles of the distributions against each other (qqplot command in MATLAB). If they line up on the $x=y$ line, that's good evidence they are the same distribution and thus the noise is normal.

Another way are hypothesis tests. You can try forms of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (might need to use the 2-sample to deal with the covariance matrix). There are multivariable versions, or you can just check that linear combinations are normal (that's one way to characterize a multivariate normal), and you can check all possible combinations (difficult if the dimension is high). Another popular test for this is the Royston test. If you're using R there's a good package for these types of tests called [MVN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MVN/MVN.pdf). [Other tests are Mardia's test, the BHEP test, the Cox-Small test, and the Smith and Jain's adaptation of the Friedman-Rafsky test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Multivariate_normality_tests), but I haven't seen these "in the wild".

Comment: I have a very high-dimensional problem. The number of points in D is in the hundreds of thousands, so K is quite large. Not sure how to compute a Q-Q plot in this situation.

Comment: [Here's a paper for doing the Q-Q plots for multivariable situations.](http://www.isical.ac.in/~statmath/html/publication/unblinded.pdf) All of the other tests should work too.